# Meal Planner in PowerShell - How to store data well?

Tags: powershell

I've been racking my brain how to set up a meal planner that is well detailed but only know PowerShell well. Was thinking I could do something like this: (not actual code)

```
$Summer.meals = $CapreseSalad
$Summer.sides = $PotatoSalad
$CapreseSalad = 'Caprese Salad'
$CapreseSalad.ingredients = @(2x($Tomatoes),'Mozerella block','Basil')
$PotatoSalad = 'Potato Salad'
$PotatoSalad.ingredients = @(2x($RedPotatoes),'mayo','etc')

If (Season(from date-time) -eq $Summer) {
    get-random $Summer.meal and $Summer.side
    write-host '$CapreseSalad with $PotatoSalad. Shopping List:'
    write-host $CapreseSalad.ingredients
    write-host $PotatoSalad.ingredients
```

I'm not worried about formatting, I'm more trying to figure out how to store all the information in database like objects/arrays.

How can one add a `$_.ingredients` to an object and is this best practice?

My end goal is to have a meal planner that does this:

- Find date
- Determine the season for specific meals (includes all-year-round meals)
- Pull from a couple lists like `$Summer.meals` and `$YearRound.meals`
- Outputs the name of the meal, ingredients, and on which days of the week they are. Such as: Monday: Caprese Salad with Potato Salad, Tuesday: Ramen with spinach, etc.
- Ingredients needed: Tomatoes (3), Ramen packets: (3)etc...

I'm starting to believe this isn't possible or easy with PowerShell. Maybe more so a CSV and PowerShell?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I voted to close this question as this is not a question that fit StackOverflow format and is more opinion based. Check out the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to see what kind of questions are expected and in which format. That being said, I still submitted an answer. I hope it help you get started in the direction you're looking to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this is very doable in Powershell.

You'd have to use a predefined (ideally for consistency) object format (or class)

Here's a list of sample meals

```
$SampleMeals = @(
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DateAdded   = (Get-date).ToShortDateString()
        Season      = 'Summer'
        Ingredients = @{
            'Tomato'      = 3
            'Milk'        = '500ml'
            'Ground Beef' = '2 pound'
        }
        MealName    = 'Mysterious'
    },
    
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DateAdded   = (Get-date).ToShortDateString()
        Season      = 'Spring'
        Ingredients = @{
            'Tomato'      = 1
            'Milk'        = '100ml'
            'Ground Beef' = '1 pound'
        }
        MealName    = 'Mysterious Lite'
    }
)
```

You can save your meals to file and get them back into a usable format that way

```
#Save
 $SampleMeals | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path 'FilePath'

#Load
$SampleMeals = Get-Content -Path 'FilePath' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

And run queries on the list of meal in your repository

```
# Get meal from ingredients
$SampleMeals.Where({$_.Ingredients.'Ground Beef' -eq '2 pound'}) | fl

#Get meal from a specific season
$SampleMeals.Where( { $_.Season -eq 'Summer' }) | fl
```

Database wise, Json will get you so far.
If this get sufficiently big, you'll have to think about another database solution.
Local, Free and faster, you could look into Sqlite.

It's additional implementation work though so You can work with json to start with, do your logic and transition to a more robust database implementation later.

So, to answer your question.
Yes, this is perfectly doable in Powershell.